# How to unlock all accounts or unlock an account forever under parity?

Tags: contract-development, parity, accounts

I want to use an account to make some transactions at the same time. So I need to unlock this account each time when I send transaction. But because it sends at the same time, it may happens that only some transactions are unlocked, the others are not...

So I think I need to unlock all accounts. Or unlock an account forever. Is there any way that I can do it?

I find that there is a config `--unlock` can unlock some accounts when Parity start. But my accounts are increasing. So it's not useful for me...

Can you give me some advice about it? Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 2):

Just create a config file with:

```
[account]
unlock = ["0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000beef","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000cafe"]
password = ["path/to/password.file"]
```

This will keep all listed accounts unlocked with the password specified in the password.file.

Answer (score 0):

Account can be unlocked by using `personal_unlockAccount` module of JSON_RPC. It unlocks specified account for use.

> ### personal_unlockAccount
>
> Unlocks specified account for use.
>
> If permanent unlocking is disabled (the default) then the duration
>   argument will be ignored, and the account will be unlocked for a
>   single signing. With permanent locking enabled, the duration sets the
>   number of seconds to hold the account open for. It will default to 300
>   seconds. Passing 0 unlocks the account indefinitely.
>
> There can only be one unlocked account at a time.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> 1. `Address` - 20 Bytes - The address of the account to unlock.
> 2. `String` - Passphrase to unlock the account.
> 3. `Quantity` - (default: `300`) Integer or `null` - Duration in seconds how long the account should remain unlocked for.
>
> `params: [
>     "0x8f0227d45853a50eefd48dd4fec25d5b3fd2295e",
>     "hunter2",
>      null ]`
>
> #### Returns
>
> - `Boolean` - whether the call was successful
>
> #### Example:
>
> Request
>
> `curl --data '{"method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x8f0227d45853a50eefd48dd4fec25d5b3fd2295e","hunter2",null],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545`
>
> Response
>
> `{   "id": 1,
>       "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>       "result": true
>   }`

[Source](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/JSONRPC-personal-module.md#personal_unlockaccount)